# How to display Instance Tag instead of InstanceID in Grafana

Tags: monitoring, grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-templating

Is there any way to display the AWS instance name(tag) instead of instanceId?. Any variable setup is needed for this. Just want to show the tag names of all instances. Or any way to show the instanceId using variable declaration?.

---

[image]

Any way to show the tag name instead of ID. I got the instance tag in a variable, but need to add the same in the graph legend. But legend option is not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible, because CloudWatch works with dimension, where instance id is available only. Tag Name is only metadata of EC2 instance.

See https://github.com/monitoringartist/grafana-aws-cloudwatch-dashboards#aws-ec2 where are some workarounds implemented, but don't expect full tag name support everywhere.